# useEffect uses old value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

please help. When function "handleAddToken" is triggered, useEffect uses the previous old state of tokenData, instead of the new one.
It results in tokens being added in a desynchronized way (zero tokens after I add 1st token, then 1st token and I added 2nd token, etc)

Here're all of the states:

```
  // this one opens modal window where you enter values which go inside token data
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  
  // this one is to set data inside token {}
  const [tokenData, setTokenData] = React.useState({});

  // this one is a token that is added inside the array of tokens, which then is mapped as elements
  const [token, setNewToken] = React.useState<JSX.Element>();
```

The useEffect:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // tokenId is undefined at the beginning, but is defined after handleAddToken is called (see below)
    if ((tokenData as TokenData).tokenId) {
      // assembleToken returns a JSX Element that is assembled with tokenData
      setNewToken(assembleToken(tokenData as TokenData));

      // adds token inside array of other tokens (addToken is a useState state setter from another module)
      props.addToken([...props.tokenArray, token]);

      // to reset tokendata
      setTokenData({
        tokenTrueName: "",
        tokenAlias: null,
        tokenId: "",
        tokenType: "",
        tokenLabelColor: "",
        tokenStatusColor: "",
        linkedTo: null,
        tokenInitiative: 0,
        tokenHP: "",
        tokenDefense: "",
        tokenSpeed: "",
      });
    }
  }, [tokenData, token]);
```

This function is called, when I click the "Add token" button.

```
  function handleAddToken() {

    // adds additional data (other data, like tokenAlias ot trueName is being added onChange, that is triggered when you type in fields within a modal window, I didn't include this function here)
    setTokenData({
      ...tokenData,
      tokenId: uuidv4(),
      tokenType: currentTokenType,
      tokenLabelColor: randomColor(),
      tokenStatusColor: "gray",
      linkedTo: null,
    });

    // closes MUI modal window
    setOpen(false);
  }
```

Whatever I tried didn't work, unfortunately

Comment: Also worth noting: there is basically never a good reason to put JSX in state. Please don't do that.

Comment: @DBS but it doesn't (at least my console doesn't throw errors), because there is a true-check in this useEffect. And even if I remove "token" dep, which might have caused the loop, the problem persists

Comment: @JaredSmith thank you, I will fix that and remember that

Comment: @DBS the reason it's not an infinite loop is that on the second time of calling `setTokenData`, it's the same as the previous time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use a setState function and you try to get the new state in the same scope it won't work because the state is async, in this case you need to separate in two useEffects

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    // tokenId is undefined at the beginning, but is defined after handleAddToken is called (see below)
    if ((tokenData as TokenData).tokenId) {
      // assembleToken returns a JSX Element that is assembled with tokenData
      setNewToken(assembleToken(tokenData as TokenData));

      // to reset tokendata
      setTokenData({
        tokenTrueName: "",
        tokenAlias: null,
        tokenId: "",
        tokenType: "",
        tokenLabelColor: "",
        tokenStatusColor: "",
        linkedTo: null,
        tokenInitiative: 0,
        tokenHP: "",
        tokenDefense: "",
        tokenSpeed: "",
      });
    }
  }, [tokenData]);

useEffect(() => {
   props.addToken([...props.tokenArray, token]);
}, [token])
```

Comment: Well, I be damned. It worked! Thank you very much, Daniel!